# Webpack + Babel: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server

I have a React project using Webpack and Babel. When I created it on an office computer, the Webpack ran fine. When I cloned the project onto my personal computer, it gave the following error:

```
ERROR in ./react_minesweeper.jsx
Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "/Users/louisstephancruz/Desktop"
at /Users/louisstephancruz/Desktop/w6d5/minesweeper/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:298:19
at Array.map (native)
at OptionManager.resolvePresets (/Users/louisstephancruz/Desktop/w6d5/minesweeper/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:269:20)
```

Here's my `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './react_minesweeper.jsx',
  output: {
    path: './',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: [/\.jsx?$/, /\.js?$/],
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx' ]
  }
};
```

Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "minesweeper",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2"
  }
}
```

My version of node is: v5.6.0
My version of npm is: 3.6.0

Comment: In case anyone asks: my personal computer is running El Capitan. (I believe the office computer is as well.)

Comment: Given that the error references `/Users/louisstephancruz/Desktop`, do you have a `/Users/louisstephancruz/Desktop/.babelrc` file in your home Desktop? If so, it seems like that may be interfering with your project since that would expect `node_modules` to be in `Desktop`, not in `Desktop/w6d5/minesweeper/`. If you delete that `.babelrc` things should work.

Comment: thanks @loganfsmyth I got the same error because my .babelrc was in the parent directory by mistake

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`npm i` or `npm install`

should install all the packages in your package.json dependencies and dev dependencies (so long as your `NODE_ENV` environment variable does not equal `production`).

---

To check if you have a particular package installed you may do:

`npm ls babel-preset-es2015`

If for some reason your `NODE_ENV` is `production` and you would like to install dev dependencies you can use:

`npm install --only=dev`

Conversely, the following may be used on production machines that are dealing with already built code and do not need access to any development dependencies:

`npm install --only=prod`

---

I'd recommend creating a `.babelrc` in the root of your repo with the following content:

`{ "presets": [ "es2015", "react" ] }`

---

For the webpack config you may want to specify some other options:

```
{ context: __dirname
, resolve: { root: __dirname, extensions: [ '.js', '.jsx', '.json' ] }
}
```

in addition to the rest of your configuration, this tells webpack where the root directory of the bundling should take place from and what file extensions to treat as modules (which extensions you can omit in `require` / `import` statements).

I'd recommend checking out webpack's [resolve.extensions](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-extensions) for more information on that bit.

Comment: I have already installed the packages. I've run npm install. I've also removed the node modules directory and reinstalled.

Comment: What is your version of node and npm? `node --version`, `npm -v`?

Comment: My version of node is: v5.6.0 My version of npm is: 3.6.0

Comment: Hold on you might have the answer here... Just created the .babelrc and now I have a new error: `Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./components/game in /Users/louisstephancruz/Desktop/w6d5/minesweeper`. Going to debug real quick

Comment: I am in fact in the correct directory (w6d5/minesweeper), but the new error still persists

Comment: I think that would mean you have a file using a import / require `'./components/game'` that does not exist at that relative path. Could also be a case sensitivity issue.

Comment: @LouisCruz What kind of file is it? You may need to resolve it if you don't include the extension

Comment: When I changed the import of `./components/game` to `./components/game.jsx` the error goes away. Now I have a new question: why is it that I have to include the '.jsx' ? It works fine on the other computer. If you'd like I can open a new question for you to answer. Sincerely want to know!

Comment: See last edit about resolve extensions in webpack, that should do it.

Comment: Dang that fixes the extension issue too! @cchamberlain, thank you!

Comment: npm ls babel-preset-es2015 is empty , so npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev is solved my problem ~

Answer (score 29):

```
npm install babel-preset-es2015
```

does that help?

Comment: Yes, I did. Just because it's in your package.json, doesn't mean you have it installed.  
Especially as it works on one computer, and not the other.

Comment: You wouldn't need the `--save-dev` flag, it's already in the package.json.

Comment: Just in case my understanding of npm is flawed, I tried installing yet again with both of those methods and neither worked. Thanks for the try though!

Comment: Just confirming, you are in the project directory, correct?  
Also, did you try `npm install`, which should install all dependencies listed.

Comment: Yes, I am in the correct directory. I've checked that many, many times just for a sanity check.

Comment: Just to verify, could you run a `npm ls`? Does it show that all dev dependencies are installed?

Comment: Yes, the dev dependencies are indeed installed. Just learned about the `npm ls` method, thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126379/discussion-between-manmeet-gill-and-louis-cruz).

Answer (score 9):

I resolved this issue when I removed .babelrc (hidden) file from "/Users/username" directory.

Comment: why is it that 90% of the places i look say to ADD a .babelrc file and you seem to be saying to remove it??  what is your reasoning for removing it?

Comment: I think the point here is that Alex had a .babelrc in their home directory (not the project directory) and it was conflicting with the project build settings. At least that was the case for me.

Comment: Same, I had a hidden `.babelrc` in the parent directory and it was blowing up for me too...

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to install the package globally.

`npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save -g`

Answer (score -1):

```
npm install babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-stage-2 --save
```

It's worked for me.