# ReactJS - Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token react components not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I return a react component like this:

```
return (
    <section style={styleObj} id="Profile" >
      <h2 className="colorHeader">{this.state.color}</h2>
      <input id="colorInput" placeholder="Enter Hex Code Here" onChange={this.changeColor.bind(this)}/>
      <div id="slider"></div>
    </section>
  );
```

This is resulting in:

```
ERROR in ./app/js/modules/colorpicker.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (31:4)

  29 |
  30 |   return (
> 31 |     <section style={styleObj} id="Profile" >
     |     ^
  32 |       <h2 className="colorHeader">{this.state.color}</h2>
  33 |       <input id="colorInput" placeholder="Enter Hex Code Here" onChange={this.changeColor.bind(this)}/>
  34 |       <div id="slider"></div>
```

To my understanding as of now, you need a babel transpiler to convert this correctly. The relevant part of my webpack config looks like this:

```
module: {
  rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      use: 'babel-loader'
    }]
  },
```

I did some more research and tried this:

```
loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query  :{
          presets:['react','es2015']
        }
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
```

This returns:

> Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "react" relative to
>   directory

[So I referenced this question and tried this:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40188578/webpack-babel-couldnt-find-preset-es2015-relative-to-directory)

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

Still get:

> Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "react" relative to
>   directory

How do I get react components to render correctly with a webpack config?

The linked answer suggests `npm ls babel-preset-es2015` which gets:

> new_platform_prototype@1.0.0 /projects/new-platform-prototype └──
>   babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1

Comment: Did you install the preset via `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-react`?

Comment: You need to install the preset via yarn or npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
npm install -D babel-preset-react babel-preset-es2015
```

This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query  :{
      presets:['react','es2015']
    }
    exclude: /node_modules/
  }
]
```

try changing jsx to js

```
  loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.js?$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query  :{
      presets:['react','es2015']
    }
    exclude: /node_modules/
  }
]
```